# What allows synthetic division to work?

Tags: polynomials

I just learned synthetic division of polynomials and was wondering what allows it to work? Why does it work?N
An example of a problem would be $(4b^3+27b^2-15b-52)/(b+7)$ 
You write the -7 in the corner, line up the coefficients
Drop down the first #
Multiply it by the -7 add it to the second number and repeat:

4. 27. -15.         -52

### -28.          7.             56

4. -1.              -8.           4

Therefore the quotient would be $4b^2-b-8+(4/b+7)$ 
Why does this work?

Comment: If you want to understand synthetic division, try doing a problem two different ways.  First use polynomial long division, then, right next to it, do the same problem with synthetic division.  See if you can figure out why a lot of the numbers you see are the same.

Comment: Ah. I see. I can't believe I didn't see that before. I'm just an idiot

Comment: We're all here to learn.

Comment: I just had like a brain fart. Thank you for helping me.